# Mail Reports scheduled job - Mailing Error

Tags: civireport, cron-job, mail

The Mail reports scheduled job was working fine until recently. We've not run any upgrades or installed any extensions for a few months now. Upon running the job manually, we get these errors:

[image: Mailing Error]

The job log however, states its been successfully run, but no mail ever gets sent out. Is there any idea how to go about debugging this to understand the cause and how to fix it?
We are running Civi 5.42.1 on Wordpress.

Comment: Is there more detail in the log?  Can you send a test mail from `Administer > System Settings > Outbound Mail` ?

Comment: Are you using any extensions for sending mail like SparkPost etc or are you just using the default mail().

Comment: @Barijohn Not using any extensions for send mail, but using SMTP.

Comment: @Aidan Thanks for this suggestion. I tried to send the test email and I get an error.
authentication failure [SMTP: Invalid response code received from SMTP server while sending email. This is often caused by a misconfiguration in Outbound Email settings. Please verify the settings at Administer CiviCRM >> Global Settings >> Outbound Email (SMTP). (code: 535, response: authentication failed (#5.7.1))]
Seems like my SMTP settings are no correct. Not sure why it has changed though - never touched it. Anyway will check it out.